# How to create yaml manifests from apache camel-k?

Tags: apache-camel, argocd, gitops, apache-camel-k

I am playing around with camel-k to build some integrations. The dev mode experience is really great. My command is `kamel run --config file:demo-template.json demo-driver.groovy --dev`

But when i am finished i would like not just remove the `--dev` switch. I would like to have some yaml files to check in into git and the deploy them with ArgoCD or Flux.

Is there something like `kamel build ... --dry-run=client -o yaml` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kamel run ... -o yaml`, for example:

```
kamel run --config file:demo-template.json demo-driver.groovy -o yaml > integration.yaml
```

Despite the `run` name, when specifying the output, it will not actually run the integration

Comment: Yeah, just remind that you cannot use `--dev` with `-o` option.